# Oracle database - identify and convert special character issues

Tags: oracle, unicode

I have some issues related to special characters in some tables. For example, some words with character `ü` were inserted in database as `NŒ`. Is there a way to find this unicode problems and convert it in a table?

I also checked `NLS_CHARACTERSET` and `LS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` `v$nls_parameters` table and it looks fine (AL32UTF8 and UTF8).

Comment: What about the session settings where you insert and query the data; and the application or operating system/shell/terminal emulator settings? You can use [the `dump()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/DUMP.html) to check the code point that is actually stored in the table.

Comment: Which tool do you use for insert and select?

Comment: maybe issue in `nlslang` ? or in some scenarios problem in computer language check this answer i provided https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963049/sql-developer-special-chars